# My Days are Numbered

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> I am faced with three signs
>
> One is shared between us
>
> One is very small
>
> One is sold again

What can I tell from these, and what does that make me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What can I tell from these, and what does that make me?

> You tell the time and that makes you a watch or clock.

I am faced with three signs

> Your face has three indicators for hours, minutes and seconds

One is shared between us

> Hour sounds like our

One is very small

> Minute

One is sold again

> Second hand

The title: My Days are Numbered

> The day and date number

Comment: I am not sure if this correct but +1 for the second hand.

Answer (score 1):

This is an awkward (and 99% wrong) solution, but I thought it might be funny. I think you are:

> **The Past, the Present, And the Future**
>
> The Present is between the other two
>
> The Past is considered to be small
>
> And... you can re-sell presents?
>
> All that and the problem is named "My Days are Numbered"
>
> Something tells me you meant that literally...
>
> Yeah this answer makes no sense but it was an idea :D

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer

Since there is the wordplay tag, I think "One is shared between us" is

> T (t). T is between us (U and S) in alphabets.

Comment: For this it would rather have the cryptic-clues tag.